# Injected dependency into automapper profile in .net core - IHttpContextAccessor returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

**Goal:** To inject `IHttpContextAccessor` as a dependency into autmapper profile 's constructor

**Why**: I need to pass in the current user 's identity 's name as part of construction of one of my domain objects

**Issue**
The obtained User identity is always null

What do I have so far?

**Startup.cs**

```
mc.AddProfile(new DtoToOtherProfile(new HttpContextAccessor()));

//OR

var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
        {
            IServiceProvider provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            mc.AddProfile(new DtoToOtherProfile(provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()));
        });
```

**DtoToOtherProfile.cs**

```
 public DtoToOtherProfile(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
     _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;

     CreateMap<MyDto, MyOther>()
    .ConstructUsing(myDto => new myOther(myDto.prop1, myDto .prop2,  _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name)); // the name is what i intend to pass
      // other mapping
    }
```

**Controller.cs**

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody]MyDto model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        // save campaign
        var myOtherModel = _mapper.Map<MyOther>(model);
        // myOtherModel.UserName is always null 
       // rest
      }
```

Is there something am missing? Pointers please?

Answer (score 15):

I believe the right way to do it is not to inject `IHttpContextAccessor` in the `Profile` but create a separate  `IValueResolver` and inject there the `IHttpContextAccessor`. So just do the following, where i want to get the user claims for the httpcontext

In your `StartUp.cs` inside `ConfigureServices` add

```
 services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
 services.AddAutoMapper();
```

Create a Profile with your mappings

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<QueryUniqueDto, QueryUnique>()
                .ForMember(s=>s.UserClaim,opt=>opt.MapFrom<IdentityResolver>());
        }
    }
```

Create the `IValueResolver`

```
public class IdentityResolver : IValueResolver<QueryUniqueDto, QueryUnique, UserClaim>
  {
    private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public IdentityResolver(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) 
    {
      _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public UserClaim Resolve(QueryUniqueDto source, QueryUnique destination, UserClaim destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return Helper.GetClaimsFromUser(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);
    }
  }
```

That's working amazing!!!

Comment: cool. let me try this and get back to you. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: although on second thought this is more like me injecting the `IHttpContextAccessor` directly on the controller and simply use that value to set the mapped object's property thus not going through mapper

Comment: You can add the service registration now via services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that AutoMapper configuration is usually singleton. It should be singleton because constructing it is quite heavy. But the username in the request is not singleton-scope. You will most likely have to find a different solution rather than using AutoMapper.

One option I though of:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

IServiceProvider provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
{
    mc.AddProfile(new DtoToOtherProfile(provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>()));
});
```

This builds the service provider and fetches the context accessor from the container. *However, this did not work.*

Comment: Thank you. I tried this as well but the real issue is that User.Identity.Name fetched from access-or is always null - this gets instantiated only at the call to the controller method and not at the mapper profile level. so was wondering if am doing it wrong or is that expected.

Comment: @Jaya did you find any solution. I am struggling for 2 days

Comment: @GeorgePapadakis There is a fundamental problem where you are reliant on a request-scope thing from a singleton-scope service (which the AutoMapper mapper *should be*, do not make it request-scope). You are most likely not going to be able to map the requesting user's username to something there.

Comment: @juunas hmm.. I see your point - request scope vs singleton (or otherwise)

Comment: @GeorgePapadakis : No real solution via mapper, but what I did was to actually inject `IHttpContextAccessor` directly into my controller and thus after mapping dto to domain i set the user property on the domain from the value i obtain from `IHttpContextAccessor`, thus having to avoid using mapper's constructor as it doesnt (did not) work whilst on the controller since its within the request's scope as pointed out by juunas i was able to use that value directly

Comment: That's exactly what i am trying to avoid and was the initial motivation to get it work with automapper. Injecting to the controller means that if i have 20 controllers with 6,7 actions...oh my god. With my solution i cleaned up the controller and move the whole claims logic to a single point. just magic...